# How to load multiple similar CSV files into sql server using batch files

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Scenario : From ftp server we will get 100's of similar text  files like xxxxx1.txt,xxxxx2.txt .. with same structure so we need to down load it and keep the files into one local folder from local folder i need to load it into sql server after loading i need to move the files into the backup / archive folder after load .
I am using batch file   to move from ftp server to local and using bcp to load files in sql server but i need to load all similar files.
.
Note:  We have to use only BCP . I can able to load single file but struggling to load set of files

it is very easy either with informatica / ssis but we need only batch files.
 please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

A `for` loop can repeat a command on a bunch of files

```
for %A in (*.csv) do type %A
```

at it's most basic. See `for /?` for more.